# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Racers#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I checked all the topics that already seem to have asked the same question, but did not get an answer. I am getting the following error when I try to create a new racer, using the new_racer_path.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Racers#new
Showing /home/dsmegha/RoR-Coursera/Mongo/raceday/app/views/racers/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"racers", :id=>""} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #1):
1  <%= form_for(@racer) do |f| %>
2  <% if @racer.errors.any? %>
3    <div id="error_explanation">
4      <h2><%= pluralize(@racer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this racer from being saved:</h2>
5
6     <ul>
```

My rake routes output :

```
$ rake routes
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    racers GET    /racers(.:format)          racers#index
           POST   /racers(.:format)          racers#create
 new_racer GET    /racers/new(.:format)      racers#new
edit_racer GET    /racers/:id/edit(.:format) racers#edit
     racer GET    /racers/:id(.:format)      racers#show
           PATCH  /racers/:id(.:format)      racers#update
           PUT    /racers/:id(.:format)      racers#update
           DELETE /racers/:id(.:format)      racers#destroy
      root GET    /                          racers#index
```

My controllers :

```
  def show
  end
  def new
     @racer = Racer.new
  end

  def create
    @racer = Racer.new(racer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @racer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @racer, notice: 'Racer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @racer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @racer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def racer_params
      params.require(:racer).permit(:number, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :group, :secs)
    end
```

My new.html.erb :

```
<h1>New Racer</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', racers_path %>
```

The starting part of _form.html.erb which is throwing the error.

```
<%= form_for(@racer) do |f| %>
  <% if @racer.errors.any? %>
```

Part of index.html.erb, from where a new racer can be created.

```
<%= link_to 'New Racer', new_racer_path %>
```

My understanding is when the new user is clicked, the new action in my controller is executed, created a new Racer and assigning it to @racer, and then the new.html.erb is rendered which in turn renders the _form. I am a rails newbie and it will be great if you will help me debug this.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried passing `local` variables to the `_form` partial? `<%= render "form", locals: { racer: @racer } %>` `<%= form_for racer ...`

Comment: Could you please post your new.html.erb file? This is the one that is rendered for the new action (rather than the edit.html.erb you've posted).

Comment: where did you define the racer_params? I can't see them on the controller. Just asking because it seems there is the end of the class controller without the private section.

Comment: @rlarcombe added the new.html.erb. Sorry about that.

Comment: @0r4cl3 Added the racer_params. It is indeed present. That was not the end of the class controller but the end of the def.

Comment: @RichPeck Tried to pass it as a local variable. I get the error undefined local variable or method `racer' for #<#<Class:0x007f4098e40770>:0x007f40993233c8>
when I change the form_for from @racer to racer (and I pass the variable from new.html.erb)

Comment: Sorry, i did not consider the other block. When are you exactly getting the error? when hitting the link or when submitting the button to create the new racer?

Comment: @0r4cl3 When hitting the link.

Comment: Strange, the link should just take you to the new.html.erb page... On there there should be the submit button that trigger the create method on you controller. can you post the whole _form partial?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your Racer model may be set up wrong.

It should be defined like:

```
# app/models/racer.rb
class Racer < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

If your Racer class does not inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, it does not respond to the `new_record?` method, and therefore the form_for won't pick up the routing properly.

Comment: I get a " undefined method `new_record?' for #<Racer:0x007f41a852f530> " error, when I try that

Comment: In that case can you please post your racer.rb -- your Racer model...? I think the problem here is that you are not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Thanks, found out my problem. Had an initialize function in racer.rb for the mongo and it had a mistake in initializing the id. Works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the code for all the parts involved

**Form partial: _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@racer) do |f| %>
  <% if @racer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@racer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this racer from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @racer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller: racers_controller.rb**

```
class RacersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_racer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
def new
  @racer = Racer.new
end

@racer = Racer.new(racer_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @racer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @racer, notice: 'Racer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @racer }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @racer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
...
private

def set_racer
  @racer = Racer.find(params[:id])
end

def racer_params
  params.require(:racer).permit(:number, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :group, :secs)
end
```

**Model: racer.rb**

```
class Racer < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**Routes: routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :racers
end
```

Make sure to run `rake db:migrate` and also restart the web server, you never know...

Comment: Thanks, found out my problem. Had an initialize function in racer.rb for the mongo and it had a mistake in initializing the id. Works now. Thanks :)